# Conditional Random Fields

Tags: c++, r, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning

Is there a training and optimization algorithm for 2-D (two dimensional) conditional random fields (CRF) suited for classification of imagery?

Has anyone used CRF package in R (http://crf.r-forge.r-project.org/html/CRF-package.html) for image classification? I would like to have a view of a working example code.
Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged differently?  Perhaps in relation to image processing, rather than particular languages?

Answer (score 2):

Look up on Markov Random Fields. Here's a link to a paper you might be interested in: [Patric Perez: Markov Random Fields and Images (1998)](https://www.irisa.fr/vista/Papers/1998_cwi_perez.pdf).

Comment: The link seems broken - and since you did not put the name of the paper nor the author in there, I can hope that I guessed the right one from the pdf name. Is the correct paper _Patric Perez: Markov Random Fields and Images (1998)_? If so, this following link should work as it is hosted by a research institute rather than privately: http://www.irisa.fr/vista/Papers/1998_cwi_perez.pdf. Could you correct the link, and possibly edit the name of the paper/author in there for future reference?

Comment: Thanks @penelope! Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it will work alone. Since image classification is about scaling and affine transformation, so the key feature for accurate image classification is preprocessing not classification algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

classification of imagery usually involves bag of words and feature pooling and stuff, whereas conditional random field is for labeling sequential data. so it might not be appropriate to use crf in this scenario.